# F# recursion inside type definition

Tags: f#, recursion

I am having some problems with trying to implement Automatic Differentiation in F#. I think the problem is down to the evaluation not being 'lazy'.

Here is my code:

```
type Diff =
    {d : double; df : Diff}
    static member (+) (x : Diff, y : Diff) =
        {d = x.d + y.d; df = x.df + y.df}
    static member (-) (x : Diff, y : Diff) =
        {d = x.d - y.d; df = x.df - y.df}
    static member (*) (x : Diff, a : double) =
        {d = x.d * a; df = x.df * a}
    static member (*) (x : Diff, y : Diff) =
        {d = x.d * y.d; df = (x.df * y) + (y.df * x)}

let rec dZero = {d = 0.0; df = dZero}

let dConst x = {d = x; df = dZero}

let dId x = {d = x; df = dConst 1.0}

let test = dId 5.0

let add (x:Diff) = (x+x).d
```

If I try to use 'add test' I get a stack overflow error, which I think is down to the definition of (+) inside my type itself relying on '+'.

Is there any way I can fix this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks, Ash

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you thought, the problem is that the F# doesn't use lazy evaluation and that the data structure you're creating is "infinite" (because `dZero` recursively references itself). When calculating the `+`, the operator calls `+` on the `df` values and that in turn invokes `+` on the `df.df` values and so on...

One way to correct this is to make the `df` member of the record explicitly lazy:

```
type Diff = 
    {d : double; df : Lazy<Diff>} 
    static member (+) (x : Diff, y : Diff) = 
        {d = x.d + y.d; df = lazy (x.df.Value + y.df.Value) } 
    static member (-) (x : Diff, y : Diff) = 
        {d = x.d - y.d; df = lazy (x.df.Value - y.df.Value) } 
    static member (*) (x : Diff, a : double) = 
        {d = x.d * a; df = lazy (x.df.Value * a) } 
    static member (*) (x : Diff, y : Diff) = 
        {d = x.d * y.d; df = lazy ((x.df.Value * y) + (y.df.Value * x)) } 

let rec dZero = {d = 0.0; df = lazy dZero} 
let dConst x = {d = x; df = lazy dZero} 
let dId x = {d = x; df = lazy dConst 1.0}
```

This will evaluate the `df` value only when it is actually used, so the `+` operation will calculate the value of `d` and only provide a lazy value for `df` (which can be evaluated if someone needs it).

Another alternative would be to make the `Diff` type a discriminated union and represent zero as a special value (rather than as a recursive record), which would work unless you use recursive references for something else. The declaration would be roughly something like:

```
type Diff = 
    | DiffValue of double * Diff
    | DiffZero 
    static member (+) // etc...
```

This would make the implementation a bit longer, because you would need to check for the `Zero` case in all the primitive operations. In this case, you would only create finite data structures (and the operators would process them eagerly).